# External webcam automatically turned on when laptop was on sleep mode

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, webcam, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 3568 and it runs on Windows 10. Something strange happened today. I exactly remember to put my laptop on sleep mode with an external webcam, have LED lights, connected to it. In midst of the night, the LED on the webcam automatically turned on. It is terrifying. When I checked the laptop after it, it was still on sleep.

How can I know what is the reason that it turned on itself?

Comment: Check the Windows system event log, there you should find details if your PC really resumed from sleep e.g. to perform a planned task. Additionally you could check `powercfg /lastwake`

Comment: @Robert I checked the event log, it was because of the laptop going from sleep mode to hibernate. Thank You for the suggestion.

Comment: So does that answer your question? If so, you should close your question.

Comment: @Daniek K Okay. I didn't know that we have to do that. I'll do now. How to do? 